# How can I initialize a class instance in a stateless function component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Using a stateful pattern, I usually initialize a kind of helper class in my constructor and consume its methods in some component lifecycle methods like below:

```
class StatefulComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.helper = new HelperClass();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.helper.doSomething();
  }

}
```

Now, I wanted to convert the same logic into a stateless function component like this:

```
const StatelessFunction = (props) => {
   this.helper = new HelperClass();

   useEffect(() => {
     this.helper.doSomething();
   }, []);

}
```

But I worried when I saw that this component is being called every prop change from the beginning.
And this made me think that my class instance is being created over and over. 
Am I wrong? Is there anything I can do for preventing re-creation of my class and use a ref instead?

I came across [useRef](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) but not sure if it fits my case.

Comment: `useEffect` + `useRef`

Comment: `useRef` needs to be initially set to null and set properly (`ref.current`) in `useEffect` to avoid recreation on render

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looking back at this and some of the comments I can see that useMemo can not be trusted to not run the HelperClass constructor again and useRef will only set the helper **after** the first render because it's initial value can't be a function. Probably useState is the easiest and most reliable way to do this:

```
const [helper] = useState(()=>new HelperClass());
```

You can use useMemo to create an instance of HelperClass and useEffect to call it. Giving them both empty array of dependencies means they will only be called "on mount". I put on mount in quotes because memo will be called only on first render and effect will be called after first render cycle is finished.

```
const StatelessFunction = props => {
  const helper = useMemo(() => new HelperClass(), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    helper.doSomething();
  }, [helper]);
  return (<JSX />);
};
```

If the only thing you'll ever do is just call doSomething and never use the helper instance again you can just do it with useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  new HelperClass().doSomething();
}, []);
```

If you do plan to use the helper instance at some later time then you could use the previous example with useMemo or useRef:

```
const helper = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  helper.current = new HelperClass();
  //only called once after first render
  helper.current.doSomething();
}, []);
//you still have the helper instance as helper.current
```

Comment: using `useRef` like that doesn't make much sense but `useMemo` does the job.

Comment: Thanks HMR and @marzelin. Using useMemo to initialize an instance is the exact thing I need. To be more clear, i will use my class helper not only once but several times especially when a specific prop change. I am now thinking why would I need to use useRef instead of useMemo while the latter has more strengths? Is there any specific case that I would prefer useRef?

Comment: @nostromo821 No difference in the useMemo or useRef example, it just comes down to preference and since it was mentioned several times I added it for completion. However; if you plan to use helper in the first render the useRef won't work because the effect will only run **after** the first render and helper.current will be undefined during the first render.

Comment: `useRef` is probably a better solution. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo): "You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance."

Comment: `useState` also doesn't guarantee that the function is only executed once. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059503/usestate-hook-mysteriously-re-executed-without-a-trace/69076925#69076925) for a demonstration where it executes multiple times. Everything that executes outside of `useEffect` is assumed side-effect-free and should be executable with arbitrary parameters without causing a problem. I don't think there's a way to guarantee that a callback is only executed once.

Comment: What `useState` guarantees is that there will only ever be once instance seen by other `useEffect` calls (and by you, except with tricks) unlike `useMemo`. So the state will appear consisten outside `useState`, except if instanciating the class cuases side effects (like registering the class globally somewhere). In that case, remove side-effectful code outside the constructor into a method, and call that method in a separate `useEffect`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for `useMemo` solution, but here's how you can do it with `useRef` + `useEffect` to clear up some confusion:

```js
const StatelessFunction = (props) => {
   const helper = useRef(); // ref is equivalent of instance prop

   useEffect(() => {
     helper.current = new HelperClass();
     helper.current.doSomething();
   }, []); // this is equivalent of componentDidMount
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just use `useRef`, no need to combine it with `useEffect`.

```
const instance = useRef();
if (!instance.current) {
  instance.current = new HelperClass();
}
```

see [React Docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#avoiding-recreating-the-ref-contents) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `useRef` allow you to have the same instance of `HelperClass` persisted across re-renders

```
const StatelessFunction = (props) => {
   const helper = useRef(new HelperClass())

   useEffect(() => {
     helper.current.doSomething();
   }, []);
}
```

Comment: you are still creating instances on every render

Comment: nice catch @marzelin https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-kowalevski-qtlz1?fontsize=14
in this case, useMemo is the way to go