# What is the proper way of initializing a class in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is more of a theory and best practice questions versus as opposed to a how-to question, but what is the proper way of initializing a class in a React component and maintaining that singular instance throughout the component's lifecycle? For example, consider this class:

```
// MyClass.ts
class MyClass {
    constructor(){
      console.log('Initialized MyClass');
    }
}
```

And the following 2 methods:

```
// Test.tsx
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const myClass = new MyClass();

const Test = memo(() => {
  // I can use myClass here
  return null;
});

export default Test;
```

This works, but if I import this component; even if I don't use it, the console statement gets printed. (By use, I mean I dont do `<Test />` anywhere)

```
// Test.tsx
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const Test = memo(() => {
  const myClass = new MyClass();
  // I can use myClass here
  return null;
});

export default Test;
```

This also works, except every time Test get's re-rendered, I get the console log statement printed.

I've even tried to solve both these problems (MyClass getting initialized even when not being used, and MyClass being re-initialized on every re-render) by using `useRef` since that's supposed to maintain state through an instance's lifecycle

```
// Test.tsx
import React, { memo, useRef } from 'react';

const Test = memo(() => {
  const myClass = useRef<new MyClass()>;
  return null;
});

export default Test;
```

But this has the same problem as method 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize your `MyClass` only once per your program's lifetime, make it a singleton:

```
class MyClass {
 // ...
}
let instance: MyClass | null = null;

// Never do `new MyClass()`, always call this.
export function getMyClass() {
  if(!instance) instance = new MyClass();
  return instance;
}
```

If you want to initialize one MyClass per component, use a read-only state atom with a lazy initializer function:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [myClass] = React.useState(() => new MyClass());
}
```

Comment: Yep, I was about to answer my own question. I changed a few search keywords and came upon this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290411/how-can-i-initialize-a-class-instance-in-a-stateless-function-component-in-react . Which is the same as the latter part of your answer. I really thought it had to do with useRef, but I guess not.

Comment: Just to add on to summarize the answer from the other post for whoever else might need to know; the reason why useState is used instead of useRef is because useRef does not allow for a function initializer. If you don't return the class instance using a function, useState will create a new instance on every re-render.