# useState hook mysteriously re-executed without a trace

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, closures

This problem might not be related to hooks, but closures, but I'm at a complete loss how that would work.

I'm programming a custom hook, and am trying to get a unique id for every callsite within a component. For this purpose, I use `useState(() => counter++)`, where `counter` is "instanciated" once per component.

Or that's the theory. The actual code does something I can't for the life of me understand at all.

The following is a minimal verifiable example of this behaviour:

```js
const { useState } = require("react");

let counter = 0;
const useFoo = () => {
  const [id] = useState(() => {
    counter++;
    console.log("indide useState, counter:", counter); // (1)
    return counter;
  });
  console.log("inside useFoo, id:", id); // (2)
  return id;
};

export const Child = () => {
  const id = useFoo();
  return (
    <button onClick={() => console.log("id:", id, "counter:", counter)}>
      Click me!
    </button>
  );
};
```

The `useFoo` hook does the following:

- It "generates" a unique id for the callsite using `useState(()=>counter++)`. It also prints out the value of `counter` after the increment.
- It returns the generated id, after printing the `id` out to console

The `Child` component does the following:

- It calls `const id = useFoo()`
- It returns a button which, when clicked, will print out the value of `id` as well as `counter`

Without clicking anything, both `console.log` inside `useFoo` are executed, as expected, and print the following to the console:

```
indide useState, counter: 1
inside useFoo, id: 1
```

Now when you press the button, you'd expect `id` inside `Child` to be `1`, right? Wrong.

Here's the output when you click the button:

```
id: 2 counter: 2
```

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-babycat-7lv1r?file=/src/child.js) a link to a codesandbox demonstrating this behavior.

Why does this happen?

In particular, how is `counter` incremented without `(1)` and `(2)` being executed?

Thank you!

Comment: Odd behaviour indeed, looks like the `useState` hook somehow tracks the `counter` value by reference instead of by value.

Comment: @Arvid Yes, something like that - although even if that were the case, you'd expect it to increment only if `counter++` were executed, which should happen only if the callback in `useState` is executed - which in turn should cause a message to appear on the console, but there _isn't any_, which makes this so strange

Comment: @Arvid I take that back, changing `log` to debug does yield a message.

Comment: I've found a way to get "consistent" values for `x`, by encapsulating `console.log` in `useEffect`. Doesn't explain this behavior yet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code with side effects must be put into `useEffect`**. The reason for this is *not* just because code that is written directly as part of the function body could be executed at arbitrary moments - but it could even be the case that the `state` outside of `useEffect` might appear inconsistent.

I don't know how an "incremental" id could be created, but by putting all side-effect relevant code into `useEffect`, you have at least a consistent view of the value returned by `useState`, and the value returned by `useState` is definitely unique. Here's an example of this:

```
const { useState, useEffect } = require("react");

let counter = 0;
const useFoo = () => {
  const [id] = useState(() => {
    counter++;
    return counter;
  });

  useEffect(() => console.log("useState returned:", id), []);
  return id;
};

export const Child = () => {
  const id = useFoo();
  return <button onClick={() => console.log("id:", id)}>Click me!</button>;
};
```

This will output

```
useState returned: 2
id: 2
```

The function body of `useFoo` should be pure; react only guarantees that the functions in `useEffect` as well as the final rendered component will have a consistent view of the state of the component.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. Hooks have a lot of magic going on in the background, so be prepared for more surprises like this :) But fortunately, most of the time, it just works as expected.