# What is the best way to create a class instance variable only once in a React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, setstate

I have a class instance variable that I create using new operator. I want this to be created only once throughout the lifecycle of a React functional component.
Should I create it outside the component or inside useEffect or use useMemo or some other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290411/how-can-i-initialize-a-class-instance-in-a-stateless-function-component-in-react

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to implement this would be to setup a **context** to store the var and then access/initialize it in the component.

Alternatively, you can also use a singleton via this package for example : [react-singleton-hook](https://github.com/Light-Keeper/react-singleton-hook) . It's less "react standard" but singleton being a well known design pattern, it may be more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Fred . Could you share your comments on the last part of my question description?